# Select the row after reloaddata is complete on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell  and datasource. 
My tableviewdelegate class is registered to callback on on an event and once I got the event, I am reloading the data on the tableview.

The call back comes after I edit the tableviewcell data. But once the callback came, when I reloaddata, the tableview is scrolling to the top; and not staying at the current selection.

So I have cached the current selected cell and trying to scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

But I am hitting a crash.

How can I scroll to that row after tabledata is loaded ?

```
{

[m_tableView reloadData];

    if(m_currentEditingCell != nullptr)
    {
        [m_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:m_currentEditingCell atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: Try reloading perticular row instead of complete tableview

Comment: What else are you doing? By default, `[tableView reloadData];` does ***not*** change the scroll position of the table. So you must have some other code that is causing the change.

Comment: I am not sure what else is happening. What could trigger the tableview scroll to the top?

Comment: Since you say *"The call back comes after I edit the tableviewcell data"* then **clearly** you have some other code performing actions, maybe even manipulating views.  So, you need to look at what else is going on, and try to eliminate causes.   For example - if you don't manually call `[m_tableView reloadData];` when *"the call back comes"*, does the table still scroll to the top? If so, then you know at least one place *not* to look.

Comment: If I skip the [m_tableView reloadData] then its not scolling to the top. Its staying there.

Comment: The following code is able to select the cell after reload.

//////////////////////////////////////
{
 [m_tableView reloadData];
 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: ([m_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([m_tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1) inSection:([m_tableView numberOfSections]-1)];

  if(m_currentCell != nullptr )
   [self selectCurrentCell:m_currentCell];
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is able to select the cell after reload.

{
 [m_tableView reloadData]; dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: ([m_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([m_tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1) inSection:([m_tableView numberOfSections]-1)]; if(m_currentCell != nullptr ) [self selectCurrentCell:m_currentCell];

}

}

Answer (score 0):

You should provide **NSIndexPath** instead of providing your tableviewcell as argument for the selector **scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition: animated:**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];
```

Comment: I just named it as currentcell, but its indexpath only